# Program type already present: androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

When trying to run the test below I keep on getting an error saying: 
'Program type already present: androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry'

Im new android programmer and I'm not sure whats going wrong. I read online that the order of the androidTestImplementation is important but when moving it around nothing happened. I still got the same error. I have also tried to clean build and then rebuild the project and the error still occurs.

Thanks for the help in advance :)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    @Test
    public void useAppContext() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();

        assertEquals("com.testing", appContext.getPackageName());
    }



}
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testing"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/Product_Selection_layouts'] } }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

//    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'


    //For bottom navigation
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/mockito-core-2.1.0.jar')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.2'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the answer, putting them in this order made mine work. This is got to be in the dependencies.

```
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this error occurred because somehow I still had an old com.android.support library in my build.gradle file after migrating to AndroidX.

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.0'
```

instead of

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0'
```

I used Android Studios 'Refactor/Migrate to AndroidX... ' to get sure that my code does not contain more references to the old support libraries and this resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by removing these lines from gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```